# How can I inject categorizedSymbolRenderer into My QgsFeatureRenderer?

Tags: qgis, c++, compilation

I try to get the categorizedSymbolRenderer value in order to render them
In all sample of code I found ( in python but not in c++ ) it said :

```
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2(expression , categories)
layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
```

In my application I want to do the same thing but in c++, so I write that :

```
lrenderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2("Sea",Categories)
pLayer->setRendererV2(lrenderer);
```

lrenderer is a QgsFeatureRendererV2 *
the build failed !!!!
the error message is : cannot convert 'QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2' to 'QgsFeatureRendererV2*' in assignment ....

How can i do ?

Comment: Sorry i forget the new , the correct syntax is : lrenderer = new QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2("Sea",Categories);